# How to handle switch from 3G to WIFI? UrlConnection TimeOut does not throw Exception

Tags: android, urlconnection

My application needs to download some big Files. I use a service for the download an show the progress in a notification. The problem is that during that download time the user can switch from 3g to WIFI. In that case the progress stops but no exception is thrown.
How do I handle this situation properly?

```
URL url = new URL(myurl);
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.setReadTimeout(10000);
conexion.setConnectTimeout(10000);
conexion.connect();
int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
// downlod the file
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(targetFilePath);

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    total += count;
    // publishing the progress....
    updateProgress(downloadNM, downloadNotification, (int)total*100/lenghtOfFile);
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}
output.flush();
output.close();
input.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the HttpClient-Library. It provides much more options than the URL class, and might help you with your problem.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

Comment: Would you mind explaining how the asker's problem can actually be solved with HttpClient? That'd be a bit more useful than a link to the documentation.

Comment: Well, chances are that HttpClient won't exhibit the same behaviour in the first place. And if it does, he will at least have much better tools at hand to solve complicated connection problems.